# Hover highlight div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers, hover

The reason why I want a `<div>` to highlight your choice is because the effect needs to be on many types of elements.

What I want to happen is that the highlight div will be ignored completely by mouse events.

The only way to do this as far as I know is by using `trigger()`.

```
$('#hover').mouseenter(function(){
    // that refers to the element below it.
    $(that).trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

However, the hover highlight div itself gets activated by a mouseenter as well:

```
$('.item').bind('mouseenter.hover', function() {
    hoverEffect(this);      
})
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uMjGg/).

How do I trigger all mouseenter events **except** for mouseenter.hover?

Or, how do I make a div being **completely ignored** by all mouse events? So it would just listen to the one below it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's possible with unbind('mouseenter') ? I can not test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [Pointer-Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/) css property like so:

```
#hover{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will teach #hover to ignore the mouse events, and propagate them through itself, to the underlying element.

This has issues in some browsers, and might have unexpected side-effects. please use responsibly and after consulting the documentation.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` doesn't work on IE7 and 8. So I can't use this solution. Thanks anyway.